# peculiar installation warning causing packages to malfunction

Tags: r, installation, xgboost

I want to install the package xgboost in R as per the instructions:

```
install.packages("drat", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")
drat:::addRepo("dmlc")
install.packages("xgboost", repos="http://dmlc.ml/drat/", type = "source")
```

The installation of the first two packages seems to work fine:

```
install.packages("drat", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0 49369    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0100 49369  100 49369    0     0  40981      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 41004

The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/sx/c5z57jp103s493xxcn9bhvwc0000gn/T//RtmpluolUL/downloaded_packages

drat:::addRepo("dmlc")
```

But the final installation of xgboost is really irregular and I couldn't fid the error in a previous post:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0100  351k  100  351k    0     0   550k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  550k
* installing *source* package ‘xgboost’ ...
** libs
clang++ -std=c++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include     -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -c xgboost_R.cc -o xgboost_R.o
In file included from xgboost_R.cc:3:
./dmlc-core/include/dmlc/omp.h:13:9: warning: Warning: OpenMP is not available, project will be compiled into single-thread code. Use OpenMP-enabled compiler to get benefit of multi-threading. [-W#pragma-messages]
#pragma message("Warning: OpenMP is not available, "                    \
        ^
1 warning generated.
clang++ -std=c++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include     -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -c xgboost_custom.cc -o xgboost_custom.o
In file included from xgboost_custom.cc:5:
In file included from ./include/xgboost/logging.h:13:
In file included from ./include/xgboost/./base.h:10:
./dmlc-core/include/dmlc/omp.h:13:9: warning: Warning: OpenMP is not available, project will be compiled into single-thread code. Use OpenMP-enabled compiler to get benefit of multi-threading. [-W#pragma-messages]
#pragma message("Warning: OpenMP is not available, "                    \
        ^
1 warning generated.
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c xgboost_assert.c -o xgboost_assert.o
clang++ -std=c++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include     -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -c amalgamation/xgboost-all0.cc -o amalgamation/xgboost-all0.o
In file included from amalgamation/xgboost-all0.cc:13:
In file included from amalgamation/../src/metric/metric.cc:6:
In file included from ./include/xgboost/metric.h:14:
In file included from ./include/xgboost/./data.h:15:
In file included from ./include/xgboost/./base.h:10:
./dmlc-core/include/dmlc/omp.h:13:9: warning: Warning: OpenMP is not available, project will be compiled into single-thread code. Use OpenMP-enabled compiler to get benefit of multi-threading. [-W#pragma-messages]
#pragma message("Warning: OpenMP is not available, "                    \
        ^
1 warning generated.
clang++ -std=c++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include     -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -c amalgamation/dmlc-minimum0.cc -o amalgamation/dmlc-minimum0.o
In file included from amalgamation/dmlc-minimum0.cc:8:
amalgamation/../dmlc-core/src/io/input_split_base.cc:26:22: warning: assigning field to itself [-Wself-assign-field]
  this->align_bytes_ = align_bytes_;
                     ^
In file included from amalgamation/dmlc-minimum0.cc:10:
In file included from amalgamation/../dmlc-core/src/data.cc:12:
In file included from amalgamation/../dmlc-core/src/data/disk_row_iter.h:19:
In file included from amalgamation/../dmlc-core/src/data/./libsvm_parser.h:13:
In file included from amalgamation/../dmlc-core/src/data/./text_parser.h:11:
./dmlc-core/include/dmlc/omp.h:13:9: warning: Warning: OpenMP is not available, project will be compiled into single-thread code. Use OpenMP-enabled compiler to get benefit of multi-threading. [-W#pragma-messages]
#pragma message("Warning: OpenMP is not available, "                    \
        ^
2 warnings generated.
clang++ -std=c++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include     -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -c rabit/src/engine_empty.cc -o rabit/src/engine_empty.o
clang++ -std=c++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include     -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -c rabit/src/c_api.cc -o rabit/src/c_api.o
clang++ -std=c++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o xgboost.so ./xgboost_R.o ./xgboost_custom.o ./xgboost_assert.o ./amalgamation/xgboost-all0.o ./amalgamation/dmlc-minimum0.o ./rabit/src/engine_empty.o ./rabit/src/c_api.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/xgboost/libs
** R
** data
** demo
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (xgboost)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/sx/c5z57jp103s493xxcn9bhvwc0000gn/T/RtmpluolUL/downloaded_packages’
```

The package does not download properly and hence it gives the following error when I try to run xgboost on a dataset:

```
Error in xgb.DMatrix(data, label = label, missing = missing) : 
  [14:53:26] amalgamation/../dmlc-core/src/io/local_filesys.cc:61: LocalFileSystem.GetPathInfo 201-225 Error:No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried making sure that you have OpenMP?

Comment: Are you passing a `model.matrix` into the `xgb.DMatrix()` function? See [this post](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1480).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1480), you should "double check if you have provided all numeric type features to xgb.DMatrix function" when you see this error.  Solved the issue for me.

Comment: Ideally this could be handled in proper error message but until it comes, this is the most likely reason for this error message (than dreaded C compilation issue)

Answer (score 0):

Try closing R then deleting your current library folder for it and re-installing it this way:

```
if(!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(xgboost)
```

`pacman`, which is a portmanteau of **Pac**kage **Man**ager,  gives you a package manager to manage the package installation instead of trying to install something manually. This is (more or less) the same reason people are use app stores or programs like `gdebi` (which grabs dependencies for you during Debian/Ubuntu installations) more and more instead of manually building programs from scratch after downloading some of the source from some mirror or dev site.

It makes sure you have all the dependencies, checks versions, checks the installation, tests the loading of the package, has automated troubleshooting steps, etc.

Comment: can you explain why/how this will help?

Comment: @BenBolker Sure well, in addition to just because it works for me, it uses a package manager to manage the package installation instead of trying to install something manually. Same reason people are using app stores more and more instead of building programs manually (basically). I've gotta say, asides from saving typing, `pacman` has saved me a million times and solved soooo many package installation questions on SO. It makes sure you have all the dependencies, checks the installation, tests the loading of the package, has automated troubleshooting steps, etc.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to do that much beyond wrapping `install_packages()` ... but then this is something of a matter of taste.

Comment: @BenBolker No Ben, with much respect I'm sorry but both parts of that statement are incorrect. It does *way* more than just that and using a package manager over chasing broken dependencies is far more of a best practice than "taste".

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe you can explain this in more detail to me (in some other venue - this comment section probably isn't the right place).  Looking at `?p_load` and (admittedly very quickly) at the source of the function, I don't see that (`?p_load` says it is `a wrapper for ‘library’ and ‘require’.  It checks  to see if a package is installed, if not it attempts to install the package from CRAN and/or any other repository in the ‘pacman’  repository list`. The only obvious advantages are that it (1) combines loading and installing (if necessary), (2) includes CRAN+Bioconductor ... (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) `install.packages()` *does* implement a package manager (i.e. manages dependencies), and I can't see where in the source code or the documentation that `pacman` enhances this functionality ... paging @TylerRinker ... ?